# proving validity using rules of inference and replacement rules.

Tags: logic

$(A \rightarrow C) \lor (B \rightarrow D) \therefore (A \land B) \rightarrow (C \lor D)$

I dont know how to start for this problem, I've done demorgan and simplification and commutation, pls help and explain

$\neg (B \rightarrow R), (F \lor Q) \leftrightarrow (R \land S),
P \leftrightarrow (F \lor R) 
\therefore   \neg (P \lor Q)$

for this one I am just as stumped, tried equivalence and simplifying

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which rules of inference?  There are many logics.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one:

$(A \rightarrow C) \lor (B \rightarrow D)$ = (Implication (rewrite conditional as disjunction))

$(\neg A \lor C) \lor (\neg B \lor D)$ = (Association)

$\neg A \lor C \lor \neg B \lor D$ = (Commutation)

$\neg A \lor \neg B \lor C \lor D$ = (DeMorgan + Association)

$\neg (A \land B) \lor (C \lor D)$ = (Implication)

$(A \land B) \rightarrow (C \lor D)$

So note: these two statements are actually equivalent!

For the second one, from $\neg (B \rightarrow R)$ you can derive $\neg R$, which means $\neg(R \land S)$, which means (by premise 2) that $\neg (F \lor
Q)$, which by DeMorgan means $\neg F$ and $\neg Q$. The $\neg R$ and $\neg F$ combined is $\neg R \land \neg F$ which by DeMorgan means that $\neg (F \lor R)$, and thus (by premise 3) $\neg P$. So, you have $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$, which means $\neg P \land \neg Q$, which by DeMorgan means $\neg (P \lor Q)$.  That is not quite a formal derivation, but at least it is the high level idea.